# moving light switch from closet outer wall to inner wall and turning it into Maestro occupancy light switch

Tags: wiring, light, motion-sensor

I want to change a closet light switch to inside the closet and make it a maestro occupancy switch.  I took the current switch off and didn’t take a picture only to find that it must be in middle of the run.  So I don’t know how to wire the Occ switch (with 2 black wires) into old switch box wires.  In old switch, I have 1 set of wires coming in from bottom that are black,red, white, ground.  In the top of the old switch box there are two sets.  One with black, red, white, ground.  One with black, white, ground(believe this is the light).  The blacks are all nutted together, the whites are all nutted together as are the grounds.  The two reds from the 3/1 wires are nutted together.  [image]There is also a ground coming from the nutted grounds and it is intertwined amongst blacks but not nutted to anything(guessing it was to the old switch)   When I pulled of old switch, there was a black jumper-like wire on bottom nut on switch that I wish I knew where it went because that what I am probably messing up. [image] I ran a 2/1 Romex (B,w,ground) to the new box and the maestro switch.  Connected the top black wire to the romex black.  The bottom black wire to the rommex white and took maestro green & ground and connected it to the rommex ground.[image]  [image]In the old box I connected the rommex black to all the other blacks, the ground to all the other grounds and the rommex “white” to the 2 reds.  Light turns on, but won’t turn off with switch nor occupancy time outs.  Tried connecting rommex “white” to old box white and breaker popped when light went out.  Not sure what to connect what to?

Comment: Can you get us a close-up of the wiring in the box please?

Comment: The way you are matching up all the colors.  Is that the way it was wired before? *Are you sure?* Or are you just operating on the hope that things were color coded?  (They're not.  The information of what things do/how to hook them is documented in only one place: *how they were connected before*). You yourself just used a white wire for a black wire; what documents *that?* (Actually you are required to re-mark the white wire with black tape.)